# Method Dispatch with UseMethod within an environment

Tags: r, oop, polymorphism, prototype, proto

I want to be able to dispatch to methods defined within an `environment`. This would allow me to define polymorphic methods for [`proto`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proto/index.html) objects (`proto` objects in turn inherit from the `environment` class). E.g.:

```
x <- proto()
x$foo               <- function(., obj) UseMethod("foo", obj)
x$foo.list          <- function(., obj) "obj is a list!"
x$foo.data.frame    <- function(., obj) "obj is a data.frame"
x$foo.default       <- function(., obj) "obj is neither a list nor a data.frame!"
```

And so I can do:

```
> x$foo(list())
[1] "obj is a list!"

> x$foo(1)
[1] "obj is neither a list nor a data.frame!"
```

However, all I get now when calling `x$foo` is

```
Error in UseMethod("foo") : 
  no applicable method for 'foo' applied to an object of class "c('proto', 'environment')"
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know how proto works, but as for environments, it works:

```
x <- environment()
x$foo               <- function(obj) { UseMethod("foo", obj) } 
x$foo.list          <- function(obj) "obj is a list!"
x$foo.data.frame    <- function(obj) "obj is a data.frame"
x$foo.default       <- function(obj) "obj is neither a list nor a data.frame!"

x$foo(list())
# [1] "obj is a list!"

x$foo(iris)
# [1] "obj is a data.frame"
```

proto seems to override the $ operator, so you may hack it like this:

```
x <- proto()
assign('.foo', function(obj) { UseMethod(".foo", obj) }, envir = x)
assign('.foo.list', function(obj)  "obj is a list2!", envir = x)
assign('.foo.data.frame', function(obj)  "obj is a data.frame2!", envir = x)
x$foo <-  function(., obj) { get('.foo', envir = .)(obj) }

x$foo(list())
x$foo(iris)
```